# How to allow a busy working thread in Espresso

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm trying to test the progress indicator of an app, which shows an indeterminate progress indicator while the view model is fetching data.

In order to test that, I'm mocking the provider that returns the data and make it block until my test gives tells it to go ahead. The basic setup looks like this:

```java
@Test
public void testProgressIndicator() {
    injectProvider(mockProvider);
    startTestActivity();

    // The mock provider now runs on a worker thread and won't finish
    // until we tell it to.

    // We should now see a progress indicator.
    onView(withId(R.id.progress_indicator)).check(
        matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)));

    // Tell the worker thread to finish up.
    mockProvider.setResult();

    // The worker thread now returns a result, the progress indicator
    // should be gone.
    onView(withId(R.id.progress_indicator)).check(
        matches(withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.GONE)));
}
```

This code is old, so the provider is using blocking code on a worker thread using `AsyncTask`.

However, Espresso normally waits for all workers to finish in order to make sure the results are not dependent on the timing. In particular, it uses the `AsyncTaskPoolMonitor` to wait for all pending `AsyncTask` objects. This is normally great, but in my case, I *want* this thread to remain busy while Espresso continues. How can I tell Espresso not to wait for this particular thread?

The cheap cop-out would be to just a `Thread` and communicate via `Handler` or something similar, but it would be nice to find a solution while retaining the setup using `AsyncTask`.

When I break into the debugger, I see that my test runner thread is stuck on the first `check()`:

```
wait:-1, Object (java.lang)
parkFor$:2137, Thread (java.lang)
park:358, Unsafe (sun.misc)
park:190, LockSupport (java.util.concurrent.locks)
await:2059, AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject (java.util.concurrent.locks)
take:442, LinkedBlockingQueue (java.util.concurrent)
gatherAnyResult:83, InteractionResultsHandler (androidx.test.espresso)
gatherAnyResult:52, InteractionResultsHandler (androidx.test.espresso)
waitForAndHandleInteractionResults:314, ViewInteraction (androidx.test.espresso)
check:300, ViewInteraction (androidx.test.espresso)
testProgressIndicator:76, MyFragmentTest (com.my.test)  <<< ***********************
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
runReflectiveCall:50, FrameworkMethod$1 (org.junit.runners.model)
run:12, ReflectiveCallable (org.junit.internal.runners.model)
invokeExplosively:47, FrameworkMethod (org.junit.runners.model)
evaluate:17, InvokeMethod (org.junit.internal.runners.statements)
evaluate:80, RunBefores (androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement)
evaluate:531, ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement (androidx.test.rule)
evaluate:20, RunRules (org.junit.rules)
runLeaf:325, ParentRunner (org.junit.runners)
runChild:78, BlockJUnit4ClassRunner (org.junit.runners)
runChild:57, BlockJUnit4ClassRunner (org.junit.runners)
run:290, ParentRunner$3 (org.junit.runners)
schedule:71, ParentRunner$1 (org.junit.runners)
runChildren:288, ParentRunner (org.junit.runners)
access$000:58, ParentRunner (org.junit.runners)
evaluate:268, ParentRunner$2 (org.junit.runners)
run:363, ParentRunner (org.junit.runners)
run:104, AndroidJUnit4 (androidx.test.ext.junit.runners)
runChild:128, Suite (org.junit.runners)
runChild:27, Suite (org.junit.runners)
run:290, ParentRunner$3 (org.junit.runners)
schedule:71, ParentRunner$1 (org.junit.runners)
runChildren:288, ParentRunner (org.junit.runners)
access$000:58, ParentRunner (org.junit.runners)
evaluate:268, ParentRunner$2 (org.junit.runners)
run:363, ParentRunner (org.junit.runners)
run:137, JUnitCore (org.junit.runner)
run:115, JUnitCore (org.junit.runner)
execute:56, TestExecutor (androidx.test.internal.runner)
onStart:388, AndroidJUnitRunner (androidx.test.runner)
run:2075, Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread (android.app)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but I think that https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource might help here

Comment: @BenP. Yes, I think that's what I was looking for! I vaguely remembered something but couldn't figure out where it is.

Comment: Actually, upon reading the docs, I believe this is for the opposite case - idling resources are meant to tell Espresso not to proceed until something is done. I'm trying to tell it to proceed even though it thinks something is still going on.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. How is the blocking implemented? My understanding is that Espresso waits for a particular set of things (e.g. running `AsyncTask`s). Are you using one of these?

Comment: @BenP. Yes, it happens to be an `AsyncTask`. `doInBackground` (in real life) fetches data, and in my test, it waits for a semaphore until the test tells it to continue (through `setResult` in the same code above).

Comment: I am not personally aware of any answer beyond “don’t use AsyncTask”. Hopefully someone else can help you solve this. Good luck!

Comment: Avoiding AsyncTasks still sounds like the best option in your case.
And if you don't want to rewrite a lot of code you can take the AsyncTask source (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java)
change the part that uses SerialExecutor to your own thread (essentially creation one more thread for async tasks) so that espresso won't know about your custom AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You should you CountingIdlingResource,
Call increment() in onPreExecute() of AsyncTask and decrement() in onPostExecute()

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource.html

Comment: Thanks! However, unless I'm mistaken, this works the other way around - creating and registering a resource will tell the framework that there is a busy resource and the system needs to wait. You can't decrement() to get the counter below 0 (it would throw an exception), and even if you could, having a negative count wouldn't undo another resource (in this case, the AsyncTask) being considered non-idle.